# jQuery how to get index of clicked element?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to have it so that when when I click on `img` I get the index of the clicked image.

So for example if I click on first image I get index 1, click on second image I get index 2, click on third image I get index 3.

Why doesn't my code below work?

```js
$('#article .click-zoom img').click(function (e) {
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="dhdhdhdh">

<div class="click-zoom" style="">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <img src="/images/imgg.png" height="100%" width="100%" alt="" class="zoom-overlay-open">
  </label>
</div>

<p>
Here is example text.
</p>

<div class="click-zoom" style="">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <img src="/images/imdd.png" height="100%" width="100%" alt="" class="zoom-overlay-open">
  </label>
</div>

<p>
Aha, you read this.
</p>

<div class="click-zoom" style="">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <img src="/images/imdd.png" height="100%" width="100%" alt="" class="zoom-overlay-open">
  </label>
</div>

</article>
```

Comment: Copy&Paste from the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/index): _"**If no argument is passed** to the `.index()` method, the return value is an integer indicating **the position** of the first element within the jQuery object **relative to its sibling elements**."_

Comment: You want: _"If `.index()` is **called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or jQuery object is passed in**, `.index()` returns an integer indicating **the position** of the passed element **relative to the original collection**."_

Comment: `$('#article .click-zoom img')` should be `$('article .click-zoom img')`

Comment: I've reworded your question to what *I think* you're asking.  It was very confusing as the tenses indicated your code worked so wasn't clear what you were trying to ask.  If it's wrong, please revert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$("#article")` is just a typo in the question.

Using `.index()` will give you the index relative to siblings, not relative to the document.  You can collate the images and then use `images.index(this)` to get the position within the images (which appears to be what you're asking).

Note that `index()` is always 0-based, so clicking the "first" will be index 0.  If you want first = 1 then just `+1`.

```js
$('article .click-zoom img').click(function (e) {
    var images = $("article .click-zoom img");
    console.log(images.index(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="dhdhdhdh">

<div class="click-zoom" style="">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/50/black/yellow" alt="" class="zoom-overlay-open">
  </label>
</div>

<p>
Here is example text.
</p>

<div class="click-zoom" style="">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/50/black/white" alt="" class="zoom-overlay-open">
  </label>
</div>

<p>
Aha, you read this.
</p>

<div class="click-zoom" style="">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/50/black/orange" alt="" class="zoom-overlay-open">
  </label>
</div>

</article>
```

Comment: You might want to replace `img` with `input`, use place holder images (e.g. https://via.placeholder.com/50) or add some styling to the `<img>` elements so that there's something visible to click on.